# Returning FileStreamResult with large video file high CPU utilization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I have the below function that is wired up to an API to return a file stream, like a video, to a http client.  If the file that is being streamed is quite large, there is a lot of CPU usage to return the data.  `EnableRangeProcessing` is important here so to allow the client to buffer the file a bit instead of returning the entire stream.

I'm curious if there is any ideas to improve this function to avoid those high CPU cycles.  I was thinking of caching the streams for a duration and expire them if the stream is not accessed again within like 45-60 seconds.  But honestly I don't know what .Net does in the background with that stream to dispose it itself.

```
public static Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileStreamResult GetContentStream(System.IO.FileInfo filePath)
{
    try
    {
        System.IO.Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath.FullName);

        var retValue = new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.FileStreamResult(stream, "application/octet-stream");
        retValue.EnableRangeProcessing = true;
        return retValue;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.LogError(ex);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you profile what your CPU is doing at those times?

Comment: It's an isolated Raspbian Buster on Pi 4.  The only thing it's doing is serving files to http clients and when the client requests that stream, that's when the CPU goes high.

Comment: I don't know enough about that setup to comment on that, but it would look reasonable to me that a $35 machine generates _some_ load when moving large amounts of bytes around. The file bytes will be untouched, but perhaps the I/O control, calculating packet checksums, whatever are executed on the CPU? Do the files live on the machine, or does it have to talk a network protocol as well to read the files? I don't think some general improvement suggestions can be given without more details.

Comment: Anyway a filestream basically is a pointer into a file and a small buffer for reading, that's not something caching is going to solve.

Comment: The files are stored locally on the Pi micro SD card. The Pi 4 is the latest and very capable little computer with a CPU that can be quite impressive in its capabilities over previous models. I was just not expecting such high CPU to open a file stream to a certain location in the file and read a bit of that file, then return that data to the client.  The client is a webpage with HTML5 <video> tag. I'm unsure if there is ways to set the "buffer amount" as maybe the client is hitting that API a lot in a short duration for just a few bytes each time. That could be something to consider.